# Form Values to same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is my first post here so i wish to say thank you in advance :).

I have searched the web looking for a solution and thought this would be the best place.

I am trying to make a page where by when a user enters some form details it will post to the right section, i have achieved this by using javascript but am looking for away to do this server side as do not want the javascript seen on the client side.

I will have a template page with a form that will be used on all pages, the only thing that changes is the right side, i will then use an admin panel to add templates such as lets say emails in (html code) that will appear on the right side of the form, when the user enters all their info, on the form click will be placed into the code on the right.

[image]

```
<!-- This is the page that is a template and is used to display the different emails -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeThis(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = name;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="customer name">
<button type="button" onclick='changeThis()' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span> Generate Code</button>

<p><!--all my html added through my admin will be in here --></p>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

<!-- This is the html that is added through CKeditor -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h4 align="right">Dear<br><small><span id='fname'></span></small></h4>
</div>
</div>


<!-- would like something like this like kajemuls reply, but to add through ckeditor -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h4 align="right">Dear<br><small><?php echo $_POST['title']; ?></small></h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_REQUEST['first_name'])){
    $first_name= $_REQUEST['first_name'];
    $last_name= $_REQUEST['last_name'];
    $city= $_REQUEST['city'];
}

?>
```

Body

```
<div style="float:left"> //left div
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div style="float:right"> //right div
    <p><?php echo $first_name;?></p>
    <p><?php echo $last_name;?></p>
    <p><?php echo $city;?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue i have with this is that <div style="float:right"> section will be added by CKeditor, so i dont think i could use <?php echo $first_name;?> as all the right side details will be in the form of HTML, when it the outputs to the front end these PHP value sure wont be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form you get the form values by $_POST. Now you can print the form values right side of the page. see the below code example.

```
//Form
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="title"/>
<input type="text" name="body"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

//It is the right side of the page where form values need to print.   
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){  //if form submit then this code will execute
?>
<div class="title"><?php echo $_POST['title']; ?></div>
<div class="body"><?php echo $_POST['body']; ?></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: i am using CKeditor to add the html template (email for instance) so can <?php echo $_POST['title']; ?> be added in with the HTML using the source option in CK. I had tried this but to no avail